# pulsating current in the PWM amplifier vs. the RMS current of the fundamental sine wave after the filter

Tags: fourier

I want to know how calculate pulsating current on FET switches in a PWM class D amplifier versus RMS current of the fundamental sine wave after the filter.
It depends on the positive and negative voltage?
Does it depend on the frequency of the PWM?
Does it depend on the modulating frequency?
What is the equation that relates them?

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! This sounds more like a better question for [SE.EE, the electronics StackExchange site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Let me know, and I'll migrate it there.

Comment: See, for example, [this question and answer there.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/501684/am-i-calculating-my-shunt-fet-power-dissipation-correctly)

Comment: To expand on @PeterK.'s comment, the instantaneous current depends a lot on the output voltage, the output filter, and the PWM frequency.  It depends somewhat on the switching efficiency and the rate of change of the output voltage (i.e., it's frequency).  These all interrelate to such an extent that it becomes a problem in electronics design to make a good class D amplifier.  Even if you're just using a class D amplifier chip, the design of the output filter (which will be on your shoulders) will be an electronics design problem.

Comment: Thanks PeterK and TimWescott fou your comments. Peter, please migrate it to SE.EE, the electronics StackExchange site.